# Why is my page aligning to the left on ipad/iphone?

Tags: css, ipad, margins

I am using `margin: auto` to center a div within my body. This works great on dektop browsers, but for some reason I just can't get it right on Safari on ipad or iphone.

I know the answer is probably ridiculously simple, but I'm banging my head against a wall here. Please can someone help?

[Live example](http://www.ks-webdesigner.com/debug/)

Comment: How wide is your `DIV`? `margin: auto` will only center an element that is smaller (not as wide) as its container.

Comment: The div has a fixed (pixel) width. I did wonder about that... I tried specifiying body width to 100% but that had no effect...

Comment: My suggestion of text-align:center seems to have been ignored - have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
text-align:center;
```

on body

That should do it

Wing

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

position: relative;

Comment: To what, the body? How will that help?